# How to find and treat the cause of an outdated composer package that is not in my composer.json?

Tags: composer-php, package

I ran `composer outdated` command:

```
$ composer outdated
phpdocumentor/type-resolver                    0.4.0   0.7.1
```

but looking inside composer.json, I see no such package.  In my case there is no `type-resolver`.

How do I find an outdated package that is missing in composer.json belongs to and how do I update it?

Comment: `composer why phpdocumentor/type-resolve`

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package "phpdocumentor/type-resolve" in your project

Comment: It should be `composer why phpdocumentor/type-resolver` - typo in package name.

Comment: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock  4.3.0  requires  phpdocumentor/type-resolver (^0.4.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer install not only packages that are listed directly in `composer.json` but also packages that are dependencies of packages that are listed in `composer.json`. Assuming you have in composer package `vendor/A` and this package requires `vendor/B` you will have installed both `A` and `B` packages.

So in your case you can run:

```
composer update phpdocumentor/type-resolver
```

to try to update this package.

Of course it does not mean it will be possible to update this way. It's possible that you might need to run:

```
composer update
```

but this will update all packages (and depends on scenario this is what you can accept or maybe you don't want to update all packages).

It's also possible that it won't be possible to update this package because other package that is used has phpdocumentor/type-resolver dependency set to for example `0.4.*` so `0.7` version is not compatible with this package and version 0.7 won't be installed

Comment: in my case it looks like some package must have this outdated dependency.  Running both commands in your answer did not update this package.